# Invoke descriptor through object.__getattribute__(type(self), attr) won't work

Tags: python, descriptor, getattribute, python-3.9

In short, I have the following information:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print('something')

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self.private_name, value)

class C:
    arg1 = Descriptor()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.arg1 = name

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'arg1':
            object.__getattribute__(type(self), attr)

c = C('Henry')
c.arg1
```

Why does `c.arg1` do nothing instead of printing out `something` as defined in `__get__`?

Obviously if I change code inside the `__getattribute__` as following alternative:

- `type(self).arg1`
- `object.__getattribute__(self, attr)`

it will work as usual.

Moreover, the following also works:

- `getattr(C, 'arg1')`

But not when I set it to `object.__getattribute__(type(self), attr)`. I am wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you passing `type(self)` instead of `self`? (Why are you implementing `__getattribute__` at all? That `__getattribute__` doesn't make sense, for at least 3 reasons.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm learning how descriptor work in general, so testing every possible cases. I'm stuck with ```object.__getattribute__(type(self), attr)``` case.

Comment: Also, when implementing `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` they should return something in all cases or raise an exception. Yours will now always return `None`. Similar for the descriptor's `__get__`. Returning `None` with side-effects makes it hard to understand and debug.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm fully aware of that, but the ```__get__``` doesn't even work. So it make a little sense to expand it even further.

Comment: If you were to return something, e.g. `return object.__getattribute__(type(self), attr)` you would realize that when accessed on the class, the Descriptor object is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object.__getattribute__` is the wrong `__getattribute__` method for looking up attributes on types. `type.__getattribute__` is the correct method.

If you call `object.__getattribute__` on a type, it will perform the attribute lookup procedure for ordinary objects. It will not search the argument's MRO, and it will not invoke descriptors unless they are found on a metaclass.

(That said, even if you switch to calling `type.__getattribute__`, your `__getattribute__` implementation won't make sense. It'll print the thing you expected it to print, but it won't make sense.)